# Does the Linguee dictionary have errors? Is "Angehörige" a correct plural form of "Angehörige/r"?

Tags: grammatical-case

I know that for plural form of all names ending with "e", you can just add "n" to the end of the word. So the plural form of "Angehörige" should be "Angehörigen". But the [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=Angeh%C3%B6rige) dictionary says that it should be "Angehörige". Moreover, there are two different sample sentences, one of them using "Angehörige" as plural, and another using "Angehörigen". Here are the two sentences:

> Das Paar lud alle Angehörigen der Familie zur Hochzeit ein.

Why **Angehörigen**?

> Nur Freunde und enge Angehörige sind zur Hochzeit eingeladen.

Why **Angehörige**, as it is plural? :(

Comment: Check this conjugation table: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Angeh%C3%B6rige

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your found examples are correct.

So yes, `Angehörige` and `Angehörigen` is correct plural of `Angehörige/r` - in the fitting case.

Like [infinitezero](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54167/does-the-linguee-dictionary-have-errors-is-angeh%C3%B6rige-a-correct-plural-form-o/54171#comment132202_54167) commented, you find in e.g. [Wiktionary-en (female)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Angeh%C3%B6rige) or [Wiktionary-en (male)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Angeh%C3%B6riger) or [Wiktionary-de](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Angeh%C3%B6rigen):

plural in form of `Angehörigen` fits for

- dative plural for strong declension both female / male
- plural for weak declension for both female / male
- plural for mixed declension for both female / male

plural in form of `Angehörige` fits for

- nominative plural for strong declension both female / male
- accusative plural for strong declension both female / male